# Dialog Box use in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to show a dialog box. I create a Normal Application in Roku. In the main scene, Extends with the scene and I created a one-child inside the main scene and tried to show dialog box and also tried to scene inside a child and it extends with component name. Here I tried as mention belove three scenarios. The first Scenario Working But Two Scenario Generates Interface, not a member. I required to use dialog box inside a child or component. Is there any Solution For this.

***First scenario:***

**main.xml**

```
<component name="RokuApp" extends="Scene">
</component>
```

Below My dialog Box Logic

**main.brs**

```
sub init()
  dialog = createObject("roSGNode", "Dialog")
  dialog.backgroundUri = "pkg:/images/rsgde_dlg_bg_hd.9.png"
  dialog.title = "Example Dialog"
  dialog.optionsDialog = true
  dialog.message = "Press * To Dismiss"
  m.top.dialog = dialog
end init()
```

***Second scenario :***

main.xml inside a create one ChildNode/another XML and combine with the Roku App.

**Child.xml**

```
<component name="Child" extends="Group">
</component>
```

**Child.brs**

```
sub init()
  dialog = createObject("roSGNode", "Dialog")
  dialog.backgroundUri = "pkg:/images/rsgde_dlg_bg_hd.9.png"
  dialog.title = "Example Dialog"
  dialog.optionsDialog = true
  dialog.message = "Press * To Dismiss"
  m.top.dialog = dialog ' ' Interface not a member of BrightScript Component (runtime error &hf3)
end init()
```

***Third Scenario :***

main.xml inside a create one Component/another XML and combine with the Roku App.

**Component.xml**

```
<component name="Component" extends="RowList">
</component>
```

**Component.brs**

```
sub init()
  dialog = createObject("roSGNode", "Dialog")
  dialog.backgroundUri = "pkg:/images/rsgde_dlg_bg_hd.9.png"
  dialog.title = "Example Dialog"
  dialog.optionsDialog = true
  dialog.message = "Press * To Dismiss"
  m.top.dialog = dialog ' Interface not a member of BrightScript Component (runtime error &hf3)
end init()
```

But, Here above all three scenarios only extends with the scene is working fine. and in another, both case generates the error Interface, not a member of BrightScript Component (runtime error &hf3) anyone knows that solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can show dialog by using code below

```js
    m.resetDialog = createObject("roSGNode", "StandardMessageDialog")
    m.resetDialog.title = "Reset All Levels!"
    m.resetDialog.message = ["You are about to reset all progress that you have made in the Game. Do you wish to proceed?"]
    m.resetDialog.buttons = ["Continue", "Cancel"]

    ' observe the dialog's buttonSelected field to handle button selections
    m.resetDialog.observeFieldScoped("buttonSelected", "onResetButtonSelected")

    ' display the dialog
    scene = m.top.getScene()
    scene.dialog = m.resetDialog
```

and for button press control write this code

```js
if m.resetDialog.buttonSelected = 0
        ' handle ok button here
        m.resetDialog.close = true

    else if m.resetDialog.buttonSelected = 1
        ' handle cancel button here
        m.resetDialog.close = true
    end if
```

you can use this code in groups too.
Hope this will help you. Cheers

Comment: Are you aware is there any way to set the selected button?

Answer (score 0):

Only Scene node has a field named "dialog". Group and RowList do not have a field named "dialog".